# Android, Anko cardView not available - unresolved reference: cardView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-cardview, anko

I am very new to android and writing an app with Kotlin and generating view with Anko.

I want to use the anko version of `cardView` but android studio has it highlighted in red with the error `unresolved reference: cardView`. There is no option to add an import if I press alt+Enter. Any ideas on why I can't see this?

Below is my `build.gradle` file for the project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.co.datakitchen.room7"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    // Anko Commons
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    // Anko Layouts
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

    // Coroutine listeners for Anko Layouts
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"
}
```

Comment: As you are using API 28 as targetSdkVersion, its recommended to use same versioned library on the card view dependency. Use 
`implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'`
instead of 
`implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'`

Comment: This didn't work @AawazGyawali

Comment: Its was expected, thats why I didn't added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line :
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'

add this line :
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:$anko_version"

Comment: ok this made `cardView` visible but broke some other stuff. I was creating views within fragments with `return UI {}.view`. Is there a new better way to do this now?

Comment: bdw anko is new library , It requires many updations, I would suggest you that please use butterknife library for view binding and other stuff.